# How to run a side task while also waiting for getch?

Tags: python, multithreading, getch

So I have this small program (using Linux):

```
import getch

while True:
  print("Hello World!")

  key = getch.getch()

  if key == 'q':
    break
```

So all it does is wait for the user to hit a key, and they displays "Hello World!" to the console. However, is there a way so that I can continuously display "Hello World!" to the console, and the only way to get it to end is if the user presses the "q" key?

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848755/how-to-use-getch-without-waiting-for-input), but it's in C++.

---

My first thought was to look up threading, however, I tried all the threads I could find and none of them worked. Then I came across the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), and it supposedly prevents "multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once."

Then I tried to use multiprocessing, but it still didn't work for me. This is how far I got using it:

```
import multiprocessing 
import getch

def test1():
  print("Hello World!")

def test2():
  key = getch.getch()

  if key == 'q':
    exit()

while True:
  p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=()) 
  p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=())

  p1.start()
  p2.start() 

  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

---

Am I missing something here? Or is there another way in which I can do something while also waiting for `getch()`? Or do I have to write this in another language that supports multithreading like C++?

Thanks

Comment: Well I want it to continuously print something out, and it will only stop once the user presses the "q" key

Comment: Not enough info in original question, detecting a button press will vary depending on your OS. However, in my opinion you are overthinking it by trying to use concurrency.

Comment: Oh I'm using Linux. And is there a different approach to this? One that doesn't use concurrency?

Comment: You can use package `keyboard` and do simple loop `while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'): print("Hello world!")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to install fetch, probably because I am on Windows at the moment, but you can implement what you want (However, is there a way so that I can continuously display "Hello World!" to the console, and the only way to get it to end is if the user presses the "q" key?) the following way:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread


def another_thread():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Working...\n")


def main_thread():
    while True:
        x = input("Press a key: \n")
        if x == "q":
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create another Thread object
    # daemon means that it will stop if the Main Thread stops
    th = Thread(target=another_thread, daemon=True)
    th.start()  # start the side Thread
    main_thread()  # start main logic
```