# Child process read from stdin in nonblocking mode in Windows environment

Tags: c++

I want to achieve nonblocking read from stdin with C++ in Windows. I have 2 applications written in C++.

Applications **A** (parent)  and the spawned applications **B** process (child). The idea is that Applications **A** will send some text to Applications **B**. Then Applications **B** must read character by character in nonblocking way.

My issue is not with Applications **A**, but with applications **B**. Can someone explain how to make Applications **B** read character by character in **nonblocking** way and if possible show how that is done correct in Windows environment?

-It was possible for me to achieve this in Mac environment by using:

**fcntl** and **read** functions.

I am sorry if i have confused you as i'm trying my best to explain the issue and would love to find a solution that can help me and others around the world with the same problem.

Comment: There are a number of different ways to do this. Try searching stack overflow again and add keywords like "overlapped IO" or "`ReadConsoleInput`"

Comment: Hi!, could you take me to any subject that solve the same problem please?

Comment: Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654504/trying-to-read-keyboard-input-without-blocking-windows-c

Comment: Try to use GetStartupInfoA to get stdin handle, and then ReadFile(Ex) function with lpOverlapped structure filled.